# Strange result when taking 2 single-precision figures away from each other in VBA

Tags: vba, single-precision

Can anyone explain me why the result of the below does not equal zero?

```
? CSng("0.199881939681229")
? CSng(0.1998819)
? CSng(CSng(0.199881939681229) - CSng(0.1998819))
```

1st line returns 0.1998819
2nd line returns 0.1998819 too
but the 3rd returns 4.470348E-08

Where is this figure coming from if both figures are represented exactly by the same value in a the single-precision data type.

Comment: That is weird it seems it should be 3.968122E-08, Any reason you are using CSNG? when i use a variable type Single i get the correct answer.

Comment: *note* i was able to duplicate this issue, weird, must be to do with how VBA is handling the conversions. when i inspect the variables they are all correct except after subtraction.

Comment: see my comment below, both numbers are being appoximated by slightly different binary strings, even though VBA is returning the same value for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems that the other answer for this was deleted so i will respond myself.

VBA is returning 0.1998819 but it is not actually storing both numbers as the same binary.

see http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=048046049057057056056049057051057054056049050050057 
and 
http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=048046049057057056056049057 .

Nearly identical but not.

mystery solved, VBA representation of floats in the immediate window was the issue.